# Disable Javascript programmatically in vb.net webbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have web page which contains Javascript, I want to load in a web browser control in vb.net (Google Chrome webkit) and then block, disable or remove Javascript from that page programmatically  I searched a lot but did not find a solution;
so does anyone know how to do that in code?

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowserControl is using the same settings as Internet Explorer.

You should disable javascript inside Internet Explorer settings.

Look at this tutorial of how to disable it:

http://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript

Comment: I know it , but I am using google chrome webkit and I need the  programmatically way

Comment: Why do you use webbrowser control? maybe you can do it in selenium.

Comment: because I'am streaming live video and online google chrome will work

Answer (score 0):

webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true